# Right angle formed at focus of parabola

Tags: conic-sections, projective-geometry

Let $S$ be the focus of the parabola and $AB$ be a focal chord. $C$ is a point lying on the parabola. Lines $CA$ and $CB$ intersect the directrix at points $P$ and $Q$. Prove that $\angle PSQ$ is $90^\circ$.

Since the directrix is the polar of $S$, the polar of $P$ must pass through $S$. So, it suffices to prove that the polar of $P$ passes through $Q$,which I was unable to prove, in particular I don't know how to use the fact about point $C$.[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason to avoid putting the entire thing into Cartesian coordinates and simply computing $\overrightarrow{SP}.\overrightarrow{SQ}=0$?

Comment: I was recalling a similar problem as above which I proved just using poles and polars , so was trying for a solution on similar lines.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608272/prove-that-the-line-xy-goes-through-a-fixed-point-where-x-y-are-on-fixed-con

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion works not just for a parabola but for any conic. From your comment, I assume that a projective explanation is what you want.  You need two background lemmas.

*Lemma 1:* conjugate points on the directrix of a conic subtend an angle of $90 ^{\circ}$ at the focus.

(In fact the focus can be defined projectively as the point through which conjugate lines are perpendicular.)

*Lemma 2:* For a conic $c$, a line $s$, its pole $S$, a point $C$ on $c$, and a chord $AB$ that passes through $S$, the points $P,Q$ of intersection of the lines $CA$ and $CB$ with $s$ are conjugate.

If $s$ and $S$ are a directrix and its corresponding focus, then Lemma 2 says the points $P$ and $Q$ are conjugate, and Lemma 1 says they subtend a $90^{\circ}$ angle at $S$.

As for the lemmas, background, terminology and proofs can be found in [Hatton's Projective Geometry, 1913](https://archive.org/details/cu31924060184045/page/n7/mode/2up).  For Lemma 1, see [pg 175](https://archive.org/details/cu31924060184045/page/n189/mode/2up).  For Lemma 2, see [pg 133](https://archive.org/details/cu31924060184045/page/n147/mode/2up). (Although the construction given on pg 133 is for the case of a circle, it can be used for any conic, and the proof works for any conic. Even if the proof used a special property of the circle, a circle can be projectively transformed into any conic and vice versa, which would prove the lemma for any conic.  See also [Article 97 on pg 179](https://archive.org/details/cu31924060184045/page/n193/mode/2up))

Comment: The proof of Lemma 2 is given for circles. How do you prove it for any general conic?

Comment: I've added to the answer.  But basically the proof given works for any conic.  Not sure why the author restricted it to a circle.